# Git pull or Git clone not working after trying to make heroku repository

Tags: git, clone, pull

Here is the error

remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.

Answer (score 1):

Look into:

```
git help repack
```

Also, a quick google search yielded some solutions that may fit your problem. That's all I have. I hope you find your answer!

Comment: Well I already googled for this error, but the solutions did not work for me, the strange thing is my colleagues are pulling the same repo and they got no issue.

Comment: This solution also worked for me with a slightly different error message during a `git clone`.